# Keycloak: Pass custom user attributes on Social Identity Provider Login

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-javascript

On registration, Keycloak provides the ability to add [custom user attributes](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_custom_user_attributes) via the Keycloak theme's registration page template via "input" elements that look something like:

```html
<input id="user.attributes.[the_custom_attribute]" name="user.attributes.[the_custom_attribute]" />
```

However, this only seems to work if the user creates an account and submits the form.

If the user were to login via a [Social Identity Provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#social-identity-providers) (google, microsoft, github, etc...) how do we go about adding custom user attributes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *Social Identity Provider* to login into application then the `customer_attribute` won't be available to you.

But if you still want that attribute to be set for that user before he/she logs in, then you can add [custom required action](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#required-action-walkthrough) to implement this feature. You can create new RequiredCustomAttribute action and enable it from Admin console.

Implement your own required action, similar to that of `org.keycloak.authentication.requiredactions.UpdateProfile` class provided by  keycloak. You can mark your `customer_attribute` as required in this new required action flow.

When you do all above things, next time when user logs in using *Social Identity Provider*, he/she will be asked to enter `custom_attribute` on next page.

Comment: This is a good answer because the attribute/s can be assigned at a single point, regardless of whether the user is registered by registration form, or via an identity provider.